# Change NPM entry point without an index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I recently published a private module to NPM which has some common code we use across a few of our services.

The code is written in ES6 and so we need to transpile it using babel before publishing to NPM. I've got a prepublish script which transpiles `src` in to `lib`.

There's no `index.js` file in this module since it's just some common code.

The problem I'm having is that when I install the module from NPM, using `require('@ourorg/ourmodule/somecode')` doesn't work (module can't be found). I instead have to use `require('@ourorg/ourmodule/lib/somecode')`.

I've tried changing the `main` field in `package.json` to many variations of `lib`, but it doesn't seem to work unless I include an `index.js` file, in which case `require('@ourorg/ourmodule')` returns whatever is exported there. One workaround I can see would be to export all the common code in an `index.js` file, but this isn't maintainable at all.

Answer (score 4):

The `main` field in `package.json` follows the same rules as normal Node imports - either it should point at a single file in particular, or it can point at a directory that has an `index.js` in it.

As far as I know, there is no way to make importing your package simply be an alias for a directory. If there was, what would `require("@ourorg/ourmodule")` return?

If it's absolutely driving you crazy having to type `lib` every time you import something, maybe you could add a step to your build process that autogenerates an `index.js` that re-exports everything at the root?

Comment: It seems like there should be an easier way to do this? We surely can't be the first people to want to have some common code as a dependency. The module works as expected if I include the `/lib/` in my require statement, even though the root folder has no `index.js`. There's really no way to say 'instead of looking at the project root, look in this folder'?

Comment: @RhysCamm: According to the responses ([1](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10506#issuecomment-191979827), [2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3953#issuecomment-158951174)) to previous requests for this feature, it's not possible to do this without changing Node's module resolution algorithm, which is effectively set in stone at this point. So I think you're out of luck, unfortunately.